# Solutions of $x^2=1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Show that in a cyclic group, the equation $x^2=1$ has no more than two solutions.

---

Since $G$ is a cyclic group, an element $x\in G$ can be written as $\langle x \rangle=\{x^n\mid n\in\mathbb{Z}\}=G$. Since $x^2=1$, the order of $x$ is $2$. Since there are only two positive divisors of $2$ (namely $1$ and $2$), there can be no more than two solutions to $x^2=1$ in a cyclic group.

I'm not sure if my reasoning is correct for this problem. Can someone let me know if I'm going in the right direction?

Comment: How does "only two positive divisors of 2" imply "no more than two solutions"?

Comment: Just because $G$ is cyclic doesn't mean that any element is a generator.

Comment: It’s not immediately clear to me how you used the hypothesis of cyclicity.

Comment: He used it in saying that $\left<x\right>=G$. @Lubin. But he's confusing $x$ with the generator for the group.

Comment: Hmm... I guess I'm not really sure how to approach the problem then. I'll do some more reading.

Comment: @TheMobiusLoops One method you could use (haven't tried myself): assume that there are more than two solutions and see where that leads you

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Let $g$ be the generator for the group, and write out all the elements of the group as $1, g, g^2, \cdots, g^{n-1}$.  Then $x$ has to be one of these, so let $x = g^k$ for $0 \le k \le n-1$.

If the cyclic group is infinite, then write it out as $\ldots, g^{-2}, g^{-1}, 1, g, g^2, \ldots$ and do the same thing.

Comment: Should we not let $x=g^k$ for $1\le k\le n$ instead of $n-1$? Otherwise we can't get the identity?

Comment: @TheMobiusLoops Ah yes.  Good catch.  I've changed it to $0 \le k \le n-1$.

Comment: But I thought the idea was that there was a least positive integer $n$ for which $g^n$=1.

Comment: if it is infinite, you also need the negative exponents...

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Thanks.

Comment: @TheMobiusLoops That's correct...what is your question?

Comment: @Goos Then would the indices not include 0 since 0 isn't positive.

Comment: @TheMobiusLoops You are confusing the order of an element with the exponent of the generator.  Every element $y$ has some smallest positive exponent $k$ such that $y^k = 1$.  That is called the order of $y$.  But we are not doing the order of any element here.  We are saying that since $g$ is a generator for the group, the entire group can be written out as $1, g, g^2, \ldots, g^{n-1}$.  Then we are letting $x$ be one of these values.

Comment: @TheMobiusLoops So in particular, when we let $x = g^k$, $k$ is not the order of any element, so it doesn't have to be positive.

Comment: @Goos Okay, that makes sense. I'm still not sure how this gets us to showing there can only be two solutions. I tried squaring $x$ so we are left with $x^2=g^{2k}$ which only equals 1 when $k=0$, but I don't think this was the right idea.

Comment: @TheMobiusLoops That is exactly the right idea.  But once you have $x^2 = g^{2k}$, note that it is equal to $1$ whenever $2k$ is a multiple of $n$.

Comment: @Goos So now I need to know when $2k$ is a multiple of $n$?

Comment: @TheMobiusLoops Yep!  Hint: $k$ is between $0$ and $n-1$, so $2k$ is between $0$ and $2n-2$.  What are the multiples of $n$ in that range?

Comment: @Goos Just $n$ and $2n$, right?

Comment: @TheMobiusLoops Between $0$ and $2n-2$ is just $0$ and $n$.  $2n$ is bigger than $2n - 2$.

Comment: Oops! Thanks for all the help. I feel like I understand what's going on a little more!

Comment: @TheMobiusLoops You're welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $G$ is finite. A finite cyclic subgroup has a unique subgroup of order $d$ for each $d\mid |G|$. But nontrivial elements for which $x^2=1$ have order $2$, so if such equation had more than two nontrivial solutions $r,s$, how many subgroups of order two would $G$ have? Of course those elements exist iff $2\mid |G|$.

If $G$ is infinite cyclic, every nontrivial element has infinite order, so $x^2=1$ gives $x=1$.

Answer (score 1):

$H:=\{x|x^2=1\}$ is a subgroup of $G$, since $G$ is abelian
$$
(xy)^2=xyxy=x^2y^2
$$
Every subgroup of a cyclic group is cyclic. If $g$ is a generator, then $H=\{1,g,g^2,\dots\}=\{1,g\}$